# Hidden form fields not appearing in MVC Model after post-back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a new MVC 4 Application with a fairly basic View/Controller. The associated Model contains a couple properties that I've mapped to **Hidden** form fields. When the Page renders the first time (*e.g. via the HttpGet Action*) it all looks fine. But when the form is Post'ed by selecting the Submit button the resulting Model presented to the Action no longer has the Hidden field values set. Here is a walkthrough of the particulars.

Here is a sample of the **Model**:

```
public class Application
{
    public bool ShowSideBars { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the initial **Controller** **Action** (*which seems to work fine*):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Application()
{
    var model = Request.ParseFromQueryString<Application>();
    model.ShowSideBars = true;

    return View(model);
}
```

This maps to the **View** as follows:

```
<fieldset>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ShowSideBars)
...
</fieldset>
```

This results in the following **mark-up** to be rendered inside the fieldset:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The ShowSideBars field is required." id="ShowSideBars" name="ShowSideBars" type="hidden" value="True" />
```

***Note**: I sure wish I knew why MVC has decided to add the '... field is required' content when I didn't flag it as required, but that's for another question*

Here is the **Action** that is called when the form is submitted. At this point the aforementioned property will no longer be set to '**true**'.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Application(Application application)
{
    // Other work done here

    return View(application);
}
```

At present, there are no custom Model Binders. Also, I've tested some other data types and I'm seeing the same thing.

Can someone explain why hidden form values are not being returned? Am I just doing this all wrong?

Comment: The `data-val-required` is being rendered because the model type is `bool`. Bools by default are required, they have to be true or false. If you don't want to see the data-val-required, make the property a `bool?`.

Comment: As an aside, Data Annotations adds 'required' to any non-nullable type. Ints and Bools will automagically be marked as required.

Comment: @danludwig Great idea! thanks. This will prevent a little bloat in the overall page size.

Comment: Is the ShowSlideBars initially on the query string?

Comment: I'm assuming that you've wrapped the field within a form named "application" and that you're passing other fields back to the model that are getting filled in?

Comment: @Dismissile No, that's why I'm setting it in the controller. Eventually, this will be set by more dynamic processes.

Comment: @CAbbott Yes, all the Model properties that are not mapped to Hidden fields are all comming back just fine. It just seems to be Hidden fields.

Comment: Please try this on MVC 3 and report results. If your problem occurs on prerelease software (Beta), try to reproduce the problem with the released software. Generally you can reproduce the problem in the released software. By posting that you are using beta software you omit 95% of the potential help and obscure this issue. If it only repro’s on Beta, point that out and you’ll get a quick response because that’s a vital breaking that the product team will be motivated to fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the issue (ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta running on VS 2010 .NET 4.0).

Model:

```
public class Application
{
    public bool ShowSideBars { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Application()
    {
        var model = new Application();
        model.ShowSideBars = true;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Application(Application application)
    {
        return Content(application.ShowSideBars.ToString());
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Application

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ShowSideBars)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

When I submit the form, the model binder correctly assigns the `ShowSideBars` property in the POST action to true.

> Note: I sure wish I knew why MVC has decided to add the '... field is
>   required' content when I didn't flag it as required, but that's for
>   another question

That's because non-nullable types such as booleans are always required. You could stop ASP.NET MVC helpers from emitting HTML5 data-* client side validation attributes for them by putting the following line in `Application_Start`:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

Comment: Can't explain it, but when I applied the changes to the Models and the View to support nullable types for the hidden fields it all started working. Thanks.

Comment: I believe MVC flagged the field as required because bool is not a nullable type.  If you want to remove the requirement, you would need to use bool? as the type.

Answer (score 10):

If you have the property in your model decorated with a ReadOnlyAttribute the value will not be populated back into the model for you.  After all, it is read only.

Comment: i created the same error by having a private setter for the field

Comment: i had a property that was 'internal' set. yep, that did it (vs helper for adding properties from written code added the property as internal set

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem. The form didn't submitted the hidden property because the model class didn't had a proper **getter and setter** for that property.
I know that is not the issue you had, just figured it might help other people that will lend in this page.

Comment: If we use `internal set;` for **setter**, the value will not be posted.

Answer (score 6):

I think the fields MUST be within the form html tags for the hidden ones to be posted back and not ignored

Comment: This is true. Putting all hidden field inside form tag solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class Model
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool InvisibleProperty { get; set; }
}
```

more info [here (ScaffoldColumn(bool value) vs HiddenInput(DisplayValue = bool value) in MVC)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/scaffoldcolumnbool-value-vs-hiddeninputdisplayvalue-boo/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had declared a field instead of a property:

```
public BaseController.Modes Mode;
```

doesn't work. But:

```
public BaseController.Modes Mode { get; set; }
```

works. The default model binder only works with properties.

Answer (score 0):

I kid you not, this is another reason it could happen.

**My form had the same field in it twice.**  The other field was actually not in the form, but that doesn't matter.

Run this jQuery in the developer console to see how many elements come back:

```
$("[id$=PropertyName]"); // Search for ids ending with property name.
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, in Core 6 the solution was removing **[Editable(false)]** attribute from the model class Id property which I wanted to tunnel through get/post as a hidden form field. In .Net 4.8 it was not a problem.